# Is it possible to ignore quotes in a variable used in a string built out for a shell_exec?

Tags: php

I'm working with an older PHP project and have a command that is built out for shell_exec that looks like the following

```
trim(shell_exec("mono /test/path/test.exe \"".$sUserID."\" \"".$sPassword."\""));
```

I have surrounded the username and password with double quotes so most special characters can be used when it runs and uses the username and password. The only issue I've found now is that some passwords may contain double-quotes. These double quotes cause the escape to end early. So the shell command could look like this and cause an error.

```
mono /test/path/test.exe "username" "PassWo"RD"
```

Is there a way to still surround the username and password with the double quotes so they are escaped and ignore any double quotes used in the password? Or is just avoiding double quotes the best route? Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59210605/shell-exec-in-php-is-removing-the-double-quotes-from-an-json-variable-argument-c) answer your question?

Comment: You can take instead of direct call shell script or power shell script, depends on your server, you have for example ScriptTest.ps1 ***shell_exec('C:\Users\Test\ScriptTest.ps1')*** . And ScriptTest.ps1 call your exe with password.

Comment: `shell_exec("mono /test/path/test.exe " . escapeshellarg($sUserID) . " " . escapeshellarg($sPassword));`